# How to find nested html element without ID in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
<div id="content_heading">
   <span id="status">
       <h1><em>Some Element</em></h1>
   </span>
 </div>
```

I wanted to get `h1` and `$('span h1')` is not working. 
Also `$$('h1')` returns an array and i can get first element from array as `$$('h1')[0]`
Is there any way to find more accurate element something like `$('div#content_heading span h1')`?

Comment: @Jørgen I wanted `DOM element h1`

Comment: `$('span h1')` returns `null`. I am testing on js console inside firebug so DOM is ready for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you run the code after DOM is ready:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function(){
    var header = $$("span h1")[0];
});
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W5cLf/2/).

Answer (score 1):

did you try `$$('span  h1')`? $$ always returns an array you can get first element of this array if you have only one element.

Element.select method can also be used to get h1 from span#status

```
$('status').select("h1")
```

Also make sure your elements are already present in dom.